# The Female N'vios

Tags: names, women, riddle, navi-prophets

Name the females who where also n'vios (prophetesses)?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/507/shiva-mi-yodeya/564#564 ?

Comment: It is, but I have a more serious critique: It's not a real question. In other words, I doubt that anyone who knew there were seven official prophetesses but didn't know who they were would ask the question here. It's just something you look up.

Comment: @Yahu Wasn't that an answer? Are questions that were once answers also considered duplicates?

Comment: @Yahu It appears not, [see here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).

Comment: @IsaacMoses So seems like a riddle to me. Let's close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sarah
2. Chana
3. Devorah
4. Avigail
5. Chuldah
6. Esther
7. Miriam

Comment: What's the source please?

Comment: As an "official" list, all in one place, it's in Megillah 14a.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/507/shiva-mi-yodeya/564#564 ?

Comment: The _g'mara_ there also says there were prophets _kiflyaim k'yotz'e Mitzrayim_. Any reason to think that no more than seven of them were female?